# Install RVM with current ruby and rails installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am using `Rails 3.2.14` and Ruby `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]` with out having RVM.

I need to use Rails 2.3 besides my current Rails version on the same machine. I have searched for what allows me to use both of them on the same machine and I found its RVM.

I am using `Oh-My-ZSH` and I have typed this command to install RVM

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After installation I got this warning

```
  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/home/dexter/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile
```

And i don't know what should i do with my current ruby and rails.
**What is the needed steps to use both of Rails 3 and Rails to and what about the previous warning also what about by the following**

```
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
➜  ~  which ruby
ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby
```

when I type rvm list:

```
rvm list

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

also when i try to go to my project which is called Triton

```
➜  ~  cd ~/Desktop\ item/Triton
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `no rvm rubies installed yet` because there are no rubies in rvm scope. Your 'main', system ruby has nothing common with ruby's installed with rvm, that's intentional. You should install ruby in rvm with:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

if you want specific pathlevel.

You can use it with

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

if you want specific pathlevel. you should create then new gemset with

```
rvm gemset create PutNameHere
```

and then use it by (it should be done automatically if i remeber correctly)

```
rvm gemset use PutNameHere
```

since then you should install gems in regular way, they should go into specific gemset with specific ruby version.

Edit: If you want to install `ruby 1.8.6` with `rails 2` you should:

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.6 # this may take a while
rvm use ruby-1.8.6
rvm create gemset Triton # or any other name you like
rvm gemset use Triton
gem install rails -v '~> 2.3' # or an other version you want, but much better will be to do:
bundle install #of course in your app root directory - it will install all necessary gems     altogeter with rails 2 or whatever you have specified
```

Comment: Gemset is used to define what rails version i want to use in the project ?

Comment: Yes, gemset is used to store all gems within one bundle, you can create several gemsets and switch between them easily. If you will completely mess up gems within one - no problem, just delete whole gemset, create new and do `bundle install`, you should receive fresh working install (if Gemset is ok).

Comment: Can you please add to your answer , if want to use also rails 2 with ruby 1.8.6 ? i am a little confused :/

Comment: do you mean if i want to start a project in rails 2 , i should type rvm use ruby 1.8.6 then rails new ? this will be in rails 2.3.
and if i want to start a project in rails 3 i should type rvm use ruby 1.9.3 then rails new ?

Comment: ruby != rails, these are two different things. You should specify ruby AND rails so if you want to start new project you should install rails first with revision you want.

Comment: and i will work with every version like its a different machine right ?

Comment: You should specify all gems' versions in Gemfile. So install only ruby with rails, start project and then add desired gems (rails too) to your project's Gemfile and since then just do `bundle install`, installing gems manually is not a good option.

Comment: thanks alot :) , now i can imagine that RVM make me handle ruby and rails by the desired version like i am not in the same machine , every version of ruby has its own gems.

Comment: Exactly. Glad to help ;)

Comment: I`m not using facebook or an other social page, SO is the only one. I don't like such data aggregators ;)

Comment: i have installed ruby with rvm but when i type which ruby i get ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby , i am working with zsh , is there something missing ?

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/731 It seems to be caused by zsh plugin or configuration, unfortunately they haven't specified what exactly to do, so you're on your own with this, i'm not using zsh so i don't know what to do with it, try disabling all plugins as has been said there.

Answer (score 3):

Install ruby any version you need with rvm. 
For example

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ gem install rails -v 2.3
```

To return to your system version of ruby with its gemset use

```
$ rvm use system
$ ruby -v
(Should be) ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
```

To switch to 1.8.7 (for exxample) use

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
```

Also you can use rvm for both version of rails with one ruby version - try gemsets

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194
$ rvm gemset create rails2
$ rvm gemset use rails2
$ gem install rails 2.3
$ rvm gemset create rails3
$ rvm gemset use rails3
$ rvm install rails -v 3.2.14
```

for full info about gemsets look at http://rvm.io/gemsets

Answer (score 1):

I've had this warning and continued on with my installation without issue...can you type in 'rvm list', and does it recognize rvm as a command? Are you encountering a problem with your rails install further down the line?

Comment: Your rvm should be fine. Just continue with your installation. 'rvm install ruby 1.9.3' then 'gem install rails'

Comment: what about my current ruby and rails ? i have them before i install RVM.

Comment: So keep them if you wish so ;) They shouldn't interfere with rvm. Edit: sorry, i thought it's comment under my post ;p